# Finding area of Quadrilateral using Triangles

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, area, quadrilateral

> Find the area given the following description: From an iron post, proceed 500 m northeast to the brook, then 300 m east along the brook to the old mill, then 200 m S 15° E to a post on the edge of Wiggin's Road and finally along Wiggin's Road back to the iron post.

For this problem, I was told to assume that whenever the word northeast, southwest, or some other combination of cardinal directions was used, then the bearing would be 45°.

I tried drawing this picture, but I can't figure out the angles I need to find the areas of the triangles (I was thinking of dividing the figure into 2 triangles and then using either of the formulas $\sqrt{(s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$, $\frac{bh}{2}$, or $\frac{1}{2}bc \sin C$ where C is the angle between sides $b$ and $c$.

Any help on how to draw the problem and solve for the angles would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Oops.  I forgot to put the distance in the picture.  post to brook is $500$, $m\angle Post-brook-mill = 135$ (going from NE to due E).  Brook to old mill is $300$.  $m\angle brook-mill-wiggins=105$ (going from due east to south ($90$ and eat by $15$ degrees).  And old mill to wiggins rd is $200$.

So .... have at it.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to divide the quadrilateral into two triangles: the triangle Post-Brook-Old Mill and the triangle Post-Old Mill-Wiggin's Road.

Below is the guideline of the solution:

1. Find the area of the triangle Post-Brook-Old Mill using your sine formula
2. Find the distance between the Post and Old Mill using the law of cosines
3. Find the angle Brook-Old Mill-Post using the law of sine
4. Find the angle Post-Old Mill-Wiggin's Road
5. Find the area of the triangle Post-Old Mill-Wiggin's Road using your sine formula